# Using LINQ to perform a INNER JOIN in 2 DataTables (Multiples criteria)

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable, outer-join

I know that exists a lot of solutions about how to create an OUTER JOIN between two DataTables.

I created the following code in C#:

```
DataTable vDT1 = new DataTable();
vDT1.Columns.Add("Key");
vDT1.Columns.Add("Key2");
vDT1.Columns.Add("Data1");
vDT1.Columns.Add("Data2");

vDT1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA1_AAAA", "DATA2_AAAA" });
vDT1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "02", "ZZ", "DATA1_BBBB", "DATA2_BBBB" });

DataTable vDT2 = new DataTable();
vDT2.Columns.Add("Key");
vDT2.Columns.Add("Key2");
vDT2.Columns.Add("Data3");
vDT2.Columns.Add("Data4");

vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_AAAA", "DATA4_AAAA" });
vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_BBBB", "DATA4_BBBB" });
vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_CCCC", "DATA4_CCCC" });
vDT2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "01", "ZZ", "DATA3_DDDD", "DATA4_DDDD" });

DataTable vDT3 = new DataTable();
vDT3.Columns.Add("Key");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Key2");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data1");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data2");
vDT3.Columns.Add("KeyTemp1");
vDT3.Columns.Add("KeyTemp2");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data3");
vDT3.Columns.Add("Data4");

DataRow vDRnull = vDT2.Rows.Add();

var vLINQ = vDT1.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupJoin(vDT2.AsEnumerable(), 
        dr1 => new { key1 = dr1["Key"], key2 = dr1["Key2"] }, 
        dr2 => new { key1 = dr2["Key"], key2 = dr2["Key2"] },
        (dr1, result) => dr1.ItemArray.Koncat(
            ((result.FirstOrDefault<DataRow>() == null) 
                ? vDRnull 
                : result.FirstOrDefault<DataRow>()).ItemArray));

foreach (var aw in vLINQ)
{
    vDT3.Rows.Add(aw);
}
```

I implemented this extension:

```
public static T[] Koncat<T>(this T[] x, T[] y)
{
    if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("x");
    if (y == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("y");
    int oldLen = x.Length;
    Array.Resize<T>(ref x, x.Length + y.Length);
    Array.Copy(y, 0, x, oldLen, y.Length);
    return x;
}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Is easy and clean (Under my point of view); but I want to ask to the experts about some kind of recommendation, improvement or if this method have a performance flaw. Normally I need manage huge amount of data (More than 100K items)

Comment: Your question would probably be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you do this in sql instead of C#?

Comment: The new post on Code Review was posted: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107830/using-linq-to-perform-a-left-outer-join-in-2-datatables-multiples-criteria